# Split IP addresses in a CSV Cell

Tags: powershell

I am struggling in importing from a CSV file.  This file has and "IP Address" field however the program that generates the form (which I have not control over) can create a CSV file like this

```
hostname,IP Address,Site
server1,192.168.1.10,florida
Server2,192.168.10.100
192.168.10.101
8.8.8.8,Alaska
server3,10.10.10.10,Ohio
```

I import the csv into variable
`$sessions=import-csv -path $Path`

In a `foreach ($session in $sessions)` loop I try to get the IP's and split them with the following:

`` $IPs=$session."IP Address" -split "`r`n" ``

However when I check the $IPs it does not seem to be an array as for server 2 $IPs shows

```
PS c:\$IPS
 192.168.10.100
192.168.10.101
8.8.8.8
PS c:\$IPs.count
1
```

What can I do to split the Cell in to an array so I can process the IP's found in a `foreach ($IP in $IPs)` loop

Answer (score 1):

Using `` "`r`n" `` to split on newlines will fail if the input doesn't use carriage returns.

Either make the carriage return char optional in the regex pattern:

```
$IPs = $session."IP Address" -split "`r?`n"
```

Or use `-split` in unary mode, which will trim the input string and split on consecutive whitespace sequences:

```
$IPs = -split $session."IP Address"
```